# How to find a specific Trello card by card id or date

Tags: trello, search, trello-cards

Our Trello board currently has about 500 cards on it. We can easily search by card number if it's three digits long, e.g. `123`, but searching for two digit card numbers also returns three digit card numbers (with the most recent cards listed first), and the search doesn't work for a single character, so numbers below 10 can't be searched for at all (as far as I can tell).

I've also tried searching by date range as the [online documentation](https://support.atlassian.com/trello/docs/searching-for-cards-all-boards/) claims is possible, but I can only see how to search for cards created in the last *n* days (or last week, or last month, etc.), not with both a start and end date for the filter.

Is there a way via the web interface or the mobile app to easily find these early cards?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Trello but spun up a free account and didn't see card # exposed.  Is this a field that is not exposed in free accounts or is this field something else?  What operator do you use to search by card #?  I did note that *filtering* (not search) a board allows specifying "any match" vs. "exact match"  Also, using "any match" but enclosing the search string in quotation marks appeared to be the same behavior as "exact match".  Maybe the search interface you are using behaves similarly (`12=123` but `"12"<>123`) or maybe the search can be adapted instead to use filter.

Comment: It appears that it doesn't search for partial IDs. The numbers were appearing somewhere in the card details. I had a thought about searching in the HTTP requests. There is one request: `https://trello.com/1/board/<board-id>?<many-many-parameters>` that seems to return the card info, including `idShort` which appears to be the card number I'm looking for. I'll try it with Postman and see if I can extract the data.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't help more.  Good luck!